# Definition of completely regular space.

Tags: general-topology, definition

> A regular space is said to be completely regular space if for a closed set $A$ there exists a continuous function$$
> f: X \to [0,1]
> $$ 
>   such that$$
> f(A^c)=0, \quad f(A)=1.
> $$

Is this definition valid for completely regular space? If it is not correct then kindly state the correct one.

Comment: No, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quantor over points not in $A$ is missing, and the space is not necessarily assumed to be regular:

A space $X$ is called completely regular iff

> for all closed subsets $A \subseteq X$ and all $x \notin A$, there exists a continuous function $f: X \to [0,1]$ such that $f(x) = 1$ and $f[A] \subseteq \{0\}$.

We cannot ask for $f[X\setminus A] = \{0\}$! This would fail for almost all spaces, as it would imply that every closed $A$ is both closed and open.

A completely regular space is automatically regular (we can separate points and closed sets).
We often assume $X$ is $T_1$ (points are closed) as well, and then the property
can be denoted $T_{3\frac12}$. So if regular in your book implies points are closed, then demand that too for completely regular.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The definition is that for every closed set $A$ and point $x\notin A$, there is a continuous $f$ from $A$ to $[0,1]$ with $f(x)=0$ and $f(A)=1$.

What you give is the definition of a space in which every closed set is also an open set....i.e., a space in which each connected component is open and inherits the trivial (indiscrete) topology.